# Dynamic CSS (with php headers) not rendering in Linux (mint) - it works fine in Windows

Tags: php, linux, apache, dynamic-css

I have a dynamic CSS (with some values and class/id names provided by php).
the file begins with:

```
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
require("../../_Config/config.php");
```

The directory structure is (to determine the relative position of `config.php` and `css.php` files):

```
ROOT
    -[_Config]
      -config.php

    -[_Viewer]
        -[css]
          -css.php
```

I have Linux Mint 15 installed, with apache and (some) mods enabled - I noticed that `headers` mod wasn't enabled... and I enabled it, but that didn't helped. I get the css file in client, but is plain and empty.
Strange fact is that under Windows XAMPP it works fine.

Any suggestions here? Maybe the relative path is faulty? I tried several combinations, but neither worked (as I have to go up in the parent, to access `config.php` i thought it may be part of the problem).

I'm just accommodating with linux, so it's possible that solution to be very simple... or not. Anyway, if you need more details that i may have skipped here, please ask.

*EDIT:*
**Just a thought: could be a Linux permissions issue?** - if so, what would be the suggested workarounds, considering that my site is located in `/var/www/` and php is running under `www-data` user at this moment. Is it wise to chanve apache ownership?

*EDIT 2*
Checked header requests in Firebug - this one is for my file

> ```
> Connection    close
> Content-Encoding  gzip
> Content-Length    20
> Content-Type  text/css; charset: UTF-8
> Date  Thu, 03 Oct 2013 15:04:54 GMT
> Server    Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
> Vary  Accept-Encoding
> X-Powered-By  PHP/5.4.9-4ubuntu2.3
> Request Headersview source
> Accept    text/css,*/*;q=0.1
> Accept-Encoding   gzip, deflate
> Accept-Language   en-US,en;q=0.5
> Connection    keep-alive
> Cookie    PHPSESSID=3ohou7v772o20i72rli3iofdq6
> Host  192.168.1.99
> Referer   http://192.168.1.99/index.php
> User-Agent    Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101
> Firefox/24.0
> ```

Comment: I would check the .htaccess file in both systems to check everything is fine (routing and such things).

Comment: in Windows I have several .htaccess files... which one? :D ... and in linux I have to see where are located.

Answer (score 1):

This can be happened due to cache problems with vagrant, vm and linux. you can add the request parameter in the url

example

```
<link src="http://www.example.com/abc.php?v=1.0" > instead of <link src="http://www.example.com/abc.php" >.
```

Comment: so you say I should do it like this?   `<link href="./_Viewer/css/full.css.php?v=1.0" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Comment: I tried that from above, but no change... so, I f I did it right, is not the answer. If it's wrong, tell me where I'm doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved!**

It seems that the `require` statement was evil. Can't explain why (and, if somebody CAN, please post the answer).
What I did, was to replace `require` with `include` ... now I won't get any fatal error in case something goes wrong, but at least the css is loaded properly.